# Javascript toggle display in for loop

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am currently trying to toggle a div to show and hide when a user clicks on a button and it currently works. However, as i am using a for loop to display some list of data, the toggle button only shows and hides the div of the first set of data from the list and not the rest. There are multiple of the same buttons as it is being looped in a for loop and each one should toggle display the div of their current data from the list and not the first.

Is this because the id is the same for all the divs if so how would i go around fixing this?

Code:

```
<div class = "profile">
 {% for i in profile %}
 <button onclick="toggle()">Show Form</button>
 ...
 <div class ="form" id = "toggle_display">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="username">
      <button class="uploadPost" type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
 </div>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggle() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggle_display");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: can you use a class instead and use `getElementsByClassName()` access each element by its index

Comment: id is SINGLE element

Comment: @ChrisG chainging getElementById("toggle_display"); to getElementsByClassName("form") did nothing and has stopped toggling the display now

Comment: nah you were probably just doing it wrong, you either access each element by its index using `getElementsByClassName` or by giving each of them an unique id, you can't have 2 or more elements with the same id

Answer (score 0):

As epascarello already mentioned, `id` is referencing a single element. You need to make each section unique with an id.
You use the [for loop counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) (as in the below example) or use another unique id.

```
<div class="profile">
  {% for i in profile %}
  <button onclick="toggle({{ forloop.counter }})">Show Form</button>
  ...
  <div class="form" id="toggle_display_{{ forloop.counter }}">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="username">
      <button class="uploadPost" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
function toggle(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(`toggle_display_${id}`);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```